# Use private devpi server with pipenv

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, devpi

I can install my packages with `pip`, using a private, local `devpi` server. The corresponding configuration is:

```
[global]
index_url = http://mydevpi.mine/root/pypi/+simple/

[search]
index = http://mydevpi.mine/root/pypi/

[install]
trusted-host = mydevpi.mine
```

Installing then with `pip` is straightforward:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But doing the same with `pipenv` does not seem to work. This works, but is not using my local `devpi`:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"
```

And this does not work:

```
[[source]]

url = "http://devpi.dgv/root/pypi/+simple/"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"
```

How can I tell `pipenv` to use another url for `pypi`?

Comment: Can you provide an error message?  Is there a valid ssl/tls certificate for your devpi server?

Comment: Here's another interesting github issue: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2075

Answer (score 4):

Examples provided assume default install of pypi server.

**Method1: Pipfile**

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[[source]]
url = "http://localhost:8080"
verify_ssl = false
name = "home"

[dev-packages]

[packages]
requests = {version="*", index="home"}
beautifulsoup4 = {version="*", index="home"}
pandas = "*"
```

**Method2: Commandline**

```
$ pipenv install --pypi-mirror http://localhost:8080

$ pipenv update --pypi-mirror http://localhost:8080

$ pipenv sync --pypi-mirror http://localhost:8080

$ pipenv lock --pypi-mirror http://localhost:8080

$ pipenv uninstall --pypi-mirror http://localhost:8080
```

**Method3: Environment Variable**

```
export PIPENV_PYPI_MIRROR=http://localhost:8080
```

[Pipenv Docs - Advanced](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I can clarify a bit as I encounter a similar problem. There is no error message, but I see a lot of traffic to pypi.org (This traffic is unwanted)

I masked pypi.org in my hosts file and wanted to force the use of my devpi server, but then, pipenv install fails.

```
Current constraints:
  ipykernel

Finding the best candidates:

INFO:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 10.56.0.120
INFO:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): wiki.pm1a.com
INFO:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org
WARNING:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002D74F344518>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte',)': /simple/ipykernel/
INFO:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.org
WARNING:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002D74F344B00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte',)': /simple/ipykernel/
INFO:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (3): pypi.org
WARNING:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002D74F33EB70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte',)': /simple/ipykernel/
INFO:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (4): pypi.org
WARNING:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002D74F33E438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte',)': /simple/ipykernel/
INFO:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (5): pypi.org
WARNING:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002D74F33E208>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte',)': /simple/ipykernel/
INFO:pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (6): pypi.org
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pip9\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "e:\python3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pip9\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 98, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "e:\python3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pip9\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 88, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
```

I guess, it is closely related to the following issue on github: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1783

EDIT:
It seems like running `pipenv install --skip-lock` solves the issue when running against devpi (or something similar) without having access to pypi.org. This was at least the solution for me (with pipenv 11.10.0 and python 3.6.4)